# How can I use Tzaangors in my 40K Tcheentch army?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I like the Tzaangors models and would like to add them to my army, we are playing Warhammer 40k 9th edition.

The problem I'm having is the Tzaangors are not in the latest Chaos Daemons Codex (8th edition) and I don't know if they are restricted to the Age of Sigmar game or if they can be used in 40K and if they can be used in 40K - are they part of the Tzeentch faction or are they some other faction, like Thousand Sons?

Any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tzaangors are a part of the Thousand Sons faction. They aren't daemons in either 40k or AoS.

You can mix them with TZEENTCH daemons in one detachment, because TZEENTCH is a faction keyword, however they wouldn't get Objective Secured, as that requires the detachment be only THOUSAND SONS, nor would the Horrors get Objective Secured.

Alternatively, you could have one DAEMONS detachment, and one THOUSAND SONS detachment, keeping the detachment abilities. N.b. a THOUSAND SONS detachment has restrictions on how many BRAY units it can take, you would need some RUBRIC MARINES or SCARAB OCCULT TERMINATORS.